# htaccess - rewrite within same folder echo's index.php instead of variable

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder structure like /procedures/index.php

I have a htaccess file in /procedures like this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /procedure/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?search=$1
```

when I go to the url /procedures/somethinghere and in my file I am echo'ing $search it echo's index.php (the file name) instead of "somethinghere"

I have writtten a million of these and I am racking my brain not understanding why this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /procedure/index.php?search=$1 [L]
```